# Python write serial data to the second column of my .csv file

Tags: python

Im reading from my serialport data, I can store this data to .csv file. But the problem is that I want to write my data to a second or third column.

With code the data is stored in the first column:

```
file = open('test.csv', 'w', encoding="utf",newline="")
writer = csv.writer(file)


while True:
    if serialInst.in_waiting:
        packet = (serialInst.readline())
        packet = [str(packet.decode().rstrip())] #decode remove \r\n strip the newline
        writer.writerow(packet)
```

output of the code .csv file:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Data 1 |  |
| Data 2 |  |
| Data 3 |  |
| Data 4 |  |

example desired output .csv file:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Data1 | data 2 |
| Data3 | Data 4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not use the csv.writer before, but a quick read of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer), seems to indicate that you can only write one ***row*** at a time, but you are getting data one ***cell***/value at a time.

In your code example, you already have a file handle. Instead of writing one row at a time, you want to write one cell at a time. You'll need some extra variables to keep track of when to make a new line.

```
file = open('test.csv', 'w', encoding="utf",newline="")
writer = csv.writer(file)

ncols = 2 # 2 columns total in this example, but it's easy to imagine you might want more one day
col = 0   # use Python convention of zero based lists/arrays

while True:
    if serialInst.in_waiting:
        packet = (serialInst.readline())
        packet = [str(packet.decode().rstrip())] #decode remove \r\n strip the newline
        if col == ncols-1:
             # last column, leave out comma and add newline \n
             file.write(packet + '\n')
             col = 0   # reset col to first position
        else:
             file.write(packet + ',')
             col = col + 1
```

In this code, we're using the `write` method of a file object instead of using the csv module. See [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files) for how to directly read and write from/to files.